# Force Java upper cast class

Tags: java, class, casting

It is possible to force an upper cast type in java? See the example.

```
public class Animal{}

public class Dog extends Animal{}

Dog dog = new Dog();  
Animal test = dog;
```

What I have: `(test instanceof Dog)` and `(test instanceof Animal)` return true.
What I want: `(test instanceof Dog)` == false and `(test instanceof Animal)` == true

**There is a way to force test to be only an Animal?** Or the only way is creating a constructor for animal passing a dog? I was trying to avoid to create a constructor because I had a complex object, with a lot of getters/setters.

Thanks.

Comment: The underlying object **is** a `Dog`.  No amount of casting can change that.  If you want an object that **is only** an `Animal`, you'll need to create a `new Animal` somehow.

Comment: If your design depends on this it's probably broken. Show us an actual use case instead of an academic question wishing for a language feature that isn't there.

Comment: I think @OliCharlesworth got the point. Look's like it's impossible to do what I want without creating a new instance of Animal. Please, answer the question so I can give you the right answer.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why you would care if an object is an `Animal` but not a `Dog`, after all, a `Dog` is an `Animal`.  Anything that can apply to a `Dog` should be applicable to an `Animal`, else there is a design issue.

But if you must determine that, then call [`getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) (defined by `Object`) to get the `Class` object, then compare it with `Animal.class`.

```
if (Animal.class == test.getClass())
```

Comment: The problem is i'm trying to persist this Object with hibernate. When I try do persist "Dog" i got an "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity". If I persist Animal, i'm Ok. This is why I wan't "test" to be an Animal.

Comment: Supposing that test must specifically be an Animal. If the point is checking that `test` is not a `Dog`, but any other kind of `Animal`, then I guess reverting one of the original checks should suffice: `!(test instanceof Dog) and (test instanceof Animal)`. Shouldn't it?

Comment: You should use the `equals` method instead incase the 2 classes were loaded by different classloaders.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo What if there is another subclass of `Animal`, say, `Squid`?

Comment: @rgettman My point exactly. Instances of Squid would not be Dogs, but still would be Animals. The original question seemed to suggest that this was the check the questioner wanted implemented.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (test.getClass() == Animal.class) {...
```

Answer (score 1):

When you "extends", you are saying Dog **is** an Animal. I see the behavior is correct as you coded.

If you had-

```
class Animal {}
class Human {}

class Cat extends Animal{}
class Child extends Human {}
```

Cat is an Animal.

Child is A Human.

Cat is NOT a Human.

Child is NOT an Animal.

Comment: @zhong.j.yu When I wrote I knew someone was gonna say that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Test **is** an instance of Dog, and test **is** an instance of animal.

This isn't a problem, its one of the funadmentals of OO programming. Polymorphism.

Whatever reason you have for ensuring the type is exactly of Type animal is likely due to poor design.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of changing what type the instance is. you can use and instance of as if its an instance of animal.

Also a lot of setters and getters shouldn't be too much of a problem and it shouldn't have to require an input of Dog. Just have a constructor that copies all the fields in Animal directly (you can access fields directly with other objects of the same class) and it would be able to accept dog as an argument.

```
public class Animal{
    private int[] data;
    public Animal(Animal a){
        data=a.data;
        ...
    }
}
```